# Intellij Maven: Create jar with all library dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

Working with IntelliJ Idea, I want to implement the following:

I want to export an application to a jar, which contains all needed libraries. E.g. I need the AWS Java SDK libraries for S3 access, but if I upload the jar to the server and run the jar I get an NoClassDefFoundError, see below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Comparison: I created the same project in Eclipse and get no error! The jar file sizes are very different (Eclipse: ~35 MB vs. IntelliJ Idea: ~5,5 MB)!

I included the libraries via Maven and downloaded them also into the "lib" folder of my project:
[image]

[image]

As parameter in the run configurations I set "package", see screenshot below:
[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks for all your hints, I got it to work now! The trick was that I did't add the dependencies to the pom.xml file (because I thought that this would be done automatically after setting them in the Project Structure, but it didn't)!!! See also my other question: [Intellij IDEA Maven Plugin - Manage Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088277/intellij-idea-maven-plugin-manage-dependencies) and https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven.html! Add the dependencies by

1. Open pom.xml
2. Menu "Code" > "Generate" > "Dependency" (or shortcut ALT + INSERT)

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml file? It seems that you are not declaring dependencies.

Comment: I set the dependencies via the UI, see the screenshots above. I add a screenshot of my pom.xml...

Comment: Actually dependencies are not being included in your project. Note that `<dependencies/>` block is missing in your pom. You have to included them manually.

Comment: I have to agree with @bigdestroyer here, you need to put your dependencies in the pom. Otherwise Maven will not know anything about them and they will not be included.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use Maven Assembly Plugin to include dependencies:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>your.package.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and then: `mvn clean compile assembly:single`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I'll have a try. Where should I enter the "mvn clean compile assembly:single" command? in the parametes tab where I had "package"? Sorry I'm new to Maven...

Comment: Yes, in "Command line" input you have to put `clean compile assembly:single`. These are the *goals* that you want to execute. `clean` the build directory, `compile` project and finally `assembly` it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bigdestroyer! But now I get another error message, see my edit of the question.

Comment: After adding the dependencies to the pom.xml manually, this plugin did the trick! Thank you! See also the "SOLUTION" section in the question block!

Comment: If you know about IntelliJ and Maven, you can have a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088277/intellij-idea-maven-plugin-manage-dependencies ;-) Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day - I followed people asking to add this and that to the pom file, I ended up with a poo file instead.

Comment: OK now It just doesn't export.

Comment: Instead of adding `assembly::single` to the maven call you might also specify it in the pom file directly via:
`
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
`
Include this snippet right below `<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use the plugin [`shade`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). It is better than `Assembly` because it is possible to [relocate classes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) if a conflict occur.

A typical setup can look like this: (copied from the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html))

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                  <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

If size is important you can try to use the `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` to reduce size.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that I get the same error as explained in the edit of the question... The goal I set to "clean compile package" - is this correct???

Comment: I did not read the comment from @bigdestroyer but he is correct, maven will only include the dependencies that it handles. If you have jars that does not exist in any publicly available repositories, then you can add it to your local repository, or set up a repository (preffered). http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: I added the .iml file of the project, which lists the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the maven assembly plugin as suggested by Hector, he mentioned to run `mvn clean compile assembly:single`. I couldn't figure out where to run this command in Intellij.

This is what I ended up doing and successfully creating my `xxx-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file.

*View -> Tool Windows -> Maven -> <Your Package> -> Lifecycle -> right click compile -> Modify Run Configuration -> update Command line with 'compile assembly:single -f pom.xml' -> OK*.

This created a new run configuration in the Maven tool window. There, double click on the recently created *[compile]*.

You'll see the jars getting created under the target directory. Attaching a screenshot of my IntelliJ for reference.
[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For the maven-assembly-plugin compile problem, if you add `<executions>` block the SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar will be created automatically, so you don't need to modify the maven compile command.  see [https://medium.com/@randilfernando/when-to-use-maven-jar-maven-assembly-or-maven-shade-ffc3f76ba7a6#:~:text=maven%2Dassembly%2Dplugin%20%3A%20This,Java%20class%20name%20conflict%20issue](https://medium.com/@randilfernando/when-to-use-maven-jar-maven-assembly-or-maven-shade-ffc3f76ba7a6#:%7E:text=maven%2Dassembly%2Dplugin%20%3A%20This,Java%20class%20name%20conflict%20issue).

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.xxx.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```