# Intellij IDEA Maven Plugin - Manage Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, maven-plugin

I'm new to IntelliJ and Maven and tried a bit around. I imported some libraries via the Module & Project Structure Settings in the "Project Structure" window (see screenshot below), because I thought that I have to add my dependencies here. I also thought that this creates the pom.xml with dependency list automatically, but it didn't! I had to add my dependencies via following steps:

```
Open the pom.xml file > Menu "Code" > "Generate" > Popup "Dependency"
```

or by

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

Project Structure Window:

[image]

To export all my libraries I also had to add a plugin in the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>your.package.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>

       [...]

    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and set the goal via run configuration to

```
clean compile assembly:single package
```

This created me on running two jars:

```
test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar & test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

That was a lot of things to do for a beginner! My question now: Is there a shorter way to manage the project's dependencies? And what is the project structure setting really for (in case of dependency management)??? Did I do too much or something wrong?

**PS: For all who are new to Maven & IntelliJ, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven.html**

Comment: I always add the dependencies directly in the pom.xml file. I just don't trust Intellij enough I guess

Comment: Yes, that's also my actual opinion... It looks strange to me as a beginner, that I can add some dependencies there, but these settings won't have effect to the pom.xml file, as @Kuroro said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use maven you just have to add your dependencies on the pom.xml.

You also can use

```
Open the pom.xml file > Menu "Code" > "Generate" > Popup "Dependency"
```

As you do. InteliJ will add it to the classpath of the your project automatically.

Project Structure is used when you have submodule for example. It's not here to add jar.

Comment: But why can I add the dependencies there? And set their scope to provided / compile etc...

Comment: Because "project structure module" is not made to add maven jar. It's here for the configuration of each module (aka project in eclipse). In order to add maven dependencies you have to add it to your pom.xml (from scratch or with the menu code). You also can specified scope in the pom.xml with <scope>.

By the way there is autocompletion in pom.xml

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! So did I understand correctly, that the "project structure" is there to manage the libraries a project should "know", but has nothing to do with the libraries' export on creating jars via maven?

Comment: The "project structure" could be use to manage libraries but not in a maven project. In a maven project, libraries are manage by the pom.xml.

Indeed without maven, you will have to add jar on "project structure" but it's kind of a old school way ;)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :-)